# How to automatically run WINE GUI app after boot?

Tags: boot, debian, remote-desktop, wine

**I need run GUI wine app automatically after boot, to securityze run after unexpected reboot, shutdows, etc...**

I am considering add shortcut to "autostart" for GUIs maganers, but it require manually login which is not automatic. When I use autologin, it seems ok, but still I want to lock screen after autologin which can be security hazard, but i don't care, machine is VPS and protected with KVM password, so i think it should be ok. Any ideas to make it better?

**Major problem:** When I set up autologin and autostart, I cannot access GUI (already logged user) with xrdp. *It shows blank screen or immidietly reject new RD session.*

Any ideas how to run GUI wine app after boot and still have access GUI access to the started app? Should I consider VNC access?

PS: I dont like use native KVM from hypervisor due to low comfort using. Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens if you simply add the command-line option, `wine <application>`, to startup? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/65487/invoke-a-wine-installed-application-from-command-line